# The properly OOP approach in operation of lists?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, solid-principles

I have an OOP question, for example, there are lists (arrays).

Needed a mechanism that will add (save) and delete the selected values ​​from each array. The output should be for each array of its selected elements.

The logic of adding can be different for arrays.
As an example, for the `arr1` array, before adding to the list of selected ones, a certain condition is fulfilled, for others not.

**Do I think correctly?**

Arrays `arr1, arr2, arr3` - data model. They have any type of data inside.
The executor class must be responsible for operations on the array, it also allows you to add an item to the list of selected (favorites) and delete it from there.

**Question 1** - where to store the list of selected elements for each of the array?

**Question 2** - If logic with the class `ArrayHandler` is correct, I encounter a problem when the logic of the add method diverse for different arrays.

In this case I dont know how to check, is it that array, that need additional checking before adding to selected list.

```
class ArrayHandler {
    add (element) {
           // How to distinguish which input array is here to do the check before adding?
     if (element is from arr1) {
        return;
     }

      if (element is from arr2) {
          // add 
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: PHP or TypeScript?

Comment: No matter, I will try to realize this on both tools, I just want to grasp a right principe

Comment: [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) has a lot of data structures and interfaces you may want to look at and you can just add type hints to methods. But, honestly, I can't understand what your doubt is or even if it's actually about PHP.

Comment: I did not understand the meaning of  **logic should be hung before entering**

Comment: Issue is not in tools, issue in mind, in OOP principles and zone of responsibility. I just the similar logic for adding element of array to list of selected, but some arrays has additions conditions before adding to selected list.

Comment: **logic should be hung before entering** - I fixed this expression

Comment: Is what you want to have a single class instance that manipulates three arrays at the same time and has a single add method that automagically knows how to classify data?

Comment: I need only one class with, that should store selected element of array, remove them, add, but add() method could have different logic depend incoming array. 1. Method allows to add some unique element to selected elements list 2. Method allow to add only one element of array, if use tried to add the same element add() should remove this from selected list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer you in simple terms. Let me know if something is not clear.

**Question 1 - where to store the list of selected elements for each of the array?**

> Answer: If the number of arrays (which is 3 as you mentioned) is fixed, just make three members of the class, each will represent the array, and if not, then make single member have type 2D array and each item of that array contains your data array.

---

**Question 2 - If logic with the class ArrayHandler is correct, I encounter a problem when the logic of the add method diverse for different arrays.**

**How to distinguish which input array is here to do the check before adding?**

> In which array to add, this info must be in the item being added if there's only a single function for add. Otherwise, all the arrays will have separate add function, that implements their logic.

If there is completely different logic for add for each particular array, then it is best to separate to have different add function for the individual array.

You can expose only a single array function outside the class and can be called inside the single add function which is exposed. The same condition will be used to call their corresponding add functions.

---

> Example

```
type Genre = 'horror' | 'romantic' | 'actions';

interface TMovie {
   name: string;
   genre: Genre;
}

class Movies {

   constructor() {
      this.romantic = [];
      this.horror = [];
      this.action = [];
   }

   romantic: TMovie[];
   horror: TMovie[];
   action: TMovie[];

   add(item:TMovie) {
      switch (item.genre) {
         case 'actions': this.addToAction(item); break;
         case 'horror': this.addToHorror(item); break;
         case 'romantic': this.addToRomantic(item); break;
      }
   }

   private addToHorror(movie: TMovie) {
      // Some custom logic
      this.horror.push(movie);
   }

   private addToAction(movie: TMovie) {
      // Some custom logic
      this.action.push(movie);
   }

   private addToRomantic(movie: TMovie) {
      // Some custom logic
      this.romantic.push(movie);
   }

}

let a = new Movies();

a.add({ genre: 'actions', name: "Parker" });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2AnaBeKByAFge0Y36UAPhvgLYCG8wAlgMaEnoV23bwDO6A3AFC81qERADMW0ACoBZbADca0AN68oq+BTIQAXFA7BEggOZ9VUQwmQ64SCHwC+-OgBsKHDlBnyI75StV12PUQAV1ZcAAoASihlU1NgTBoOADpyKlo6KDQAbQBdEzioBKTknDxcLKg8grjilJY2eErqvygHVrTqeh1pOQUW0zL8RB7PfvzWhpp2Ub6IFsmAE0XwmmAIMi1er2jYwo4AdzW6TChV9bJk8xtd1sKoOldoZlZpznQdOuSKZYlsAEFXuxzhtItwoAAjZAUADWNXujw4zyGBE+iXqv2wAAlcMMQWQwZDoXC7oVEc9OhkPkV0d9MQAlbCULp0fGEqEQWHw1QOUztUxgAyyCjrKA-RZ-HHlRDhMhzWY7GKkqAAehVUAAykzoHRgnomVAnNhDPRlV8UYhkmA9ZhZXMwa1+apBTRhaLxX9AY07V4FQpbvc1ZrtQ89cADUaTXQzbSpuwrTaff6ak6oC63dAPdhGcyMkntFBtv6lYH1VrNKH9WRDcbTfcvpT6AmOLa5TsU-x2k4IMAxZV4BADh45hwonxeBQ6StFGYLAWXo0uAAaKDqTQ6ABEAAUKIgYcIN20HbwgA)

Comment: Thank you, it is useful for me, where to store selected element of array? And how to make method `add()` in class with different logic? I dont want to create a diffrent classes for each arrays, where logic of adding is different. Cause it can be a lot of arrays

Comment: Let me add an example then.

Comment: I'm going to write it in TS.

Comment: I am not sure need I only one class or more, Class should store selected element of array, remove them, add, but add() method could have different logic depend incoming array. 1. Method allows to add some unique element to selected elements list 2. Method allow to add only one element of array, if use tried to add the same element add() should remove this from selected list

Comment: Thank you, what if I have another list, not only movies, for example list of fruites, cars model? My lists are: `let arr1 = [1,2,3];  let arr2 = [{id: 1, value: "T"}]; let arr3 = [{id: 1, text: "VALUE"}]`

Comment: I think first you need to learn some OOP concepts, what it really is, why and how it is helpful, you're lacking the very basics of the OOP. I find C++ as the best language for OOP, you can pick whichever you like.